# htaccess : how to have 2 domains on the same site

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I have 2 domains for the same web site.
The first is the native domain of my hosting.

I want visitors to navigate with one or the other of the domain names, without it changing on their browsers.

I tested lots of syntax for htaccess ... without success

```
RewriteCond% {HTTP_HOST} ^ www.domain2.com $ [NC]<br>
RewriteRule domain2 /(.*)$ http://www.domain2.com/$1 [L, R = 301]
```

Other test

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} www.domain2.com [NC] <br>
RewriteRule ^$ https://www.domain2.com/ [L,R=301]
```

Thanks you for answers

Comment: You don't need any rewriting magic for that at all. You simply define two separate virtual hosts delivering the same content or, even more simple, you set the second domain name as a `ServerAlias` inside the host defintion of the first domain. If you only have a single http host defined, then you actually do not need to do anything, since that host will act as a default host (catch all)...

Comment: Also, if what you have at the moment is that site is really reachable through both domain names, but it changes in address bar to primary (and you have no Redirect rules set in apache), then it is probably your site/application that is issuing that redirect, so check there also